# Changing Drive Letters

Tags: vbscript, directory, usb-flash-drive

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to use a root directory with a program for flash drives. For example: I'm trying to run "E://Program/data/install.vbs" but the driver letter keeps changing. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

I think the batch version of what I am looking for is %root%\Program\data\install.bat but I still need it in vbscript form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "lock" the letter of flash drive in Computer Management is you are using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows then go to Control Panel > Disk Management
Find your drive, right click, select "change drive latter and path", click on "add" browse to a new folder on your local computer [C:\MyFlashCard].

Every time you connect your flash drive, no matter which drive latter it gets, it will be mounted to the folder you selected, so you can use the local path. [c:\MyFlashDrive\program\data\install.vbs]